# THREE.Color: Unknown color #002dff (warning/error)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to update the color after receiving the value from dat.GUI .
But, this

```
var colored = new THREE.Color(value.replace("#","0x"));
```

is throwing this warning "THREE.Color: Unknown color 0x002dff" and the 'colored' isn't updating.

value = #002dff (at that time, it keeps on changing, user input)

Edit: I know I can use this as "THREE.Color( #002dff )", but the color is changing at run time according to the user input from controls I've created using dat.GUI, so I won't be knowing the actual value that can be added to the code.

PS: It was `replace()` which was causing the problem. It's solved.

Comment: wow just pass it like `new THREE.Color("#fff000")` or etc

Comment: Only if I could. I mentioned that the value is generating from dat.GUI .

Comment: What revision of Three.js do you use? In the latest revision (r85) it works totally fine.

Comment: r84.
And I doubt it'll work as dat.GUI returns string value and the color constructor requires Hex value.
@Hellium just mentioned this in his comment.

Comment: Take a look at my answer and check its example, please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to give a **hexadecimal number**, not a string to the [`Color`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Color) constructor. Try to call the [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function:

```
var colorValue = parseInt ( value.replace("#","0x"), 16 );
var colored = new THREE.Color( colorValue );
```

Comment: Why don't you have any upvotes? Here is mine! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this ((new THREE.color("#FF00FF")),.if you want to choose a favortie color for your program .check this link out http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm  ,are got to the photoshop and their you can select the color and it shows the color code .

Answer (score 0):

`THREE.Color()` has the `.setStyle()` method.

```
var obj;
var gui = new dat.GUI();
var props = {
    color: '#002dff'
};
var colorController = gui.addColor(props, 'color');
colorController.onChange(
    function(value){
    // uncomment this to see it's working
    //var colored = new THREE.Color(value);
    //console.log(colored);
    obj.material.color.setStyle(value);
  }
);

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(2, 32, 24), new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial());
sphere.material.color.setStyle("#002dff");
scene.add(sphere);
obj = sphere;
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/r9Lg8fnc/) example. three.js r85, dat.GUI 0.6.5

PS Don't use `new THREE.Color()` to change an exisiting colour of a material, use `setXXXXX()` methods of `THREE.Color()`

Comment: `var colored = new THREE.Color(value.replace("#","0x"));`
This is where I was facing the issue as I need **colored** in **if statement** in the module. If that 'condition' wasn't required then it was already working with `color.setHex()`.

Comment: @UtkarshZaveri read carefully about constructor of `THREE.Color()` (especially the section about CSS-style _strings_) and `.setStyle()` method (in the context of using dat.GUI) [here](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Color)

Comment: Let me check then. using r85.

Comment: @UtkarshZaveri out of curiousity, any success?

Comment: just use `var colored = new THREE.Color(value);` somewhere in your code to set color and you'll know understand my question.

Comment: @UtkarshZaveri if I put it like that out of `onChange()`, then `value` will be undefined at all. Can you provide a link to your project, I'm really curious why you can't set the colour of a material in the way like I do?

Comment: That is where you are going wrong.
I need `var colored = new THREE.Color(value.replace("#","0x"));` to store the color in **colored** variable.  which later will be used to check one condition in `if statement`. 
Res, `.setStyle()` will surely work if I need it to update the material color. :)

Comment: @UtkarshZaveri Have you tried to uncomment the commented lines in my jsfiddle example and see what happens? Those ones: `//var colored = new THREE.Color(value); //console.log(colored);`

Comment: That is what I mentioned in my today's 1st reply.
Also, just check the console for value of colored after uncommenting.

Comment: @UtkarshZaveri in the log, there are lines of object with _r_, _g_, _b_ properties. Do you see something different?

Comment: It's working. The `replace` was causing the issue :(

Comment: @UtkarshZaveri Shortly: You got a color from dat.GUI as a _string_ in format `'#002dff'`. This format is totally valid for the constructor of `THREE.Color()` and doesn't need to be transformed into a hexadecimal value `0x002dff`.